# Difference between executeBatch() and executeLargeBatch() while using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, batch-processing

I am confused about when to use `executeBatch()` and `executeLargeBatch()`.
I went through the Java documents and the only difference I found is:

> `executeLargeBatch()` should be used when the returned row count may exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

I replaced `executeBatch()` with `executeLargeBatch()` but haven't found any performance improvements.

Is handling `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the only purpose?  Is there any performance advantage in one over the other?

Comment: I found this question useful because it's easy to overlook the text quoted in the question and the difference in return types.

Comment: Yes the answer was extremely useful

Answer (score 22):

Your quoted difference **is** the difference: [`executeBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--) returns `int[]` to return the counts of each update. [`executeLargeBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeLargeBatch--) returns **`long[]`** to return the counts of each update. Hence the documentation saying to use the latter if the count may exceed the capacity of `int`. E.g., they're the batch equivalents of [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-) (returns `int`) and [`executeLargeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeLargeUpdate-java.lang.String-) (returns `long`).

I wouldn't expect a performance difference of any significance; it's just a matter of not overflowing the `int` if you're potentially updating more than 2,147,483,647 rows.

Comment: and I think there will be no performance enhancement if we use `executeLargeBatch` at the places where we can use `executeBatch`